# How to place executable in to specied directory (path) under yocto buils

Tags: yocto

```
SECTION = "devel"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
EXTERNALSRC := "${THISDIR}/../../../sample-applications/sampleap/src"
inherit cmake externalsrc
inherit autotools gettext
do_compile() /*section to compile */
{
${CC} ${EXTERNALSRC}/sampleapp.c ${LDFLAGS} -o sample
}
/* To install executable in to specified D */
do_install() 
{
install -d ${D} ${bindir}## 
install -m 0755 sample  ${D} ${bindir}
}
```

I am new to Yocto build. I wrote simple .bb file. 
Here my question is how to I change my destination directory ${D}. 
I want to place my executable in different path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `D` variable represents the target rootfs. You can choose a specific folder on the target rootfs by specifying one of the prefixes defined in [bitbake.conf](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/conf/bitbake.conf) or a relative path after `${D}`.
Example:

```
...
install -d ${D}/home/root/mySamples
install -m 0755 sample ${D}/home/root/mySamples
...
```

If you want to place artifacts **outside** of the target rootfs instead, then you are actually misusing the Yocto Project. Anyway you can find the outputs of your recipe under the `<BUILD_DIR>/tmp/work/<DISTRO-TARGET>/<RECIPE_NAME>/<RECIPE_VERSION>/image` dir.

Comment: Generally, we specify where comes source, so it should be `${B}/sample`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, but it is not working,do_install() {
        install -d ${D}${bindir}
        install -m 0755 sample ${D}${bindir}
} install -d represents "treat all arguments as directory names". I want to change ${bindir} in the above line. My receipe executable go to /usr/bin/ path. I want to change the path. I tried in different ways but not succeeded . I studied in Yocto document under sectoin 3.3.13 it is possible .